# Html to excel. br in one cell

Tags: html, excel

If I add a line break in HTML and save it in Excel, I have two rows.

```
<td>
   hello<br>
   world
</td>

------------
row1 | hello
------------
row2 | world
------------
```

But I want a line break in one cell.
If you put in Excel `cmd + alt + enter`, you have that

```
------------
row1 | hello
     | world
------------
```

If I use

```
<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
```

that doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, but what are you trying to do? Please include actual details in what you're trying to do, as well as what's not actually working for you. Right now, I can only really see what 'doesn't help' from reading your question. Remember, we're not sat next to you to see what's wrong.

Comment: If you save this code: `<table><tr><td>hello<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />world</td></tr></table>` as **test.xls** you will see it works great. What other problem may you have? The above is the way to serve XLS files using HMTL. In case you are referring to copy/paste and how is that treated by your OS and installed software, than that is completely different question.